# I cant connect to my Bot via directline api

Tags: c#, botframework

I have this error message anytime I try to connect to my bot via directline:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code GatewayTimeout

I didn't have this error at first, it just appeared recently and I dont know what to do, please help. My AppID and Passwords are set correctly.

Comment: Have you checked your endpoint url? Make sure it ends with "/api/messages"

Comment: Please post your code